# Python - pandas.read_csv() ohlc data AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to load OHLCV data from a .CSV file to a Pandas dataframe using the pandas.read_csv() function.
I keep getting the same exception and can't figure out why.

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'
```

I believe this error means Python can't parse the data in the first column to datetime, because it sees it as an int? Maybe it only sees the very first part of the string: "2018" and tries to parse that?

As you can see in my code below I've tried many things, in all sorts of combinations:

```
    datapath = "OHLCV.csv"      
    dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.read_csv(   datapath,                                       
                        # header=None,
                        # names=['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'],
                        # parse_dates=['Date'],
                        # skiprows=1,                       
                         date_parser=dateparse,
                        # #infer_datetime_format=True,
                         # dtype={  'Date': str,
                                 # 'Open': float, 
                                 # 'High': float, 
                                 # 'Low': float, 
                                 # 'Close': float, 
                                 # 'Volume': float}
    )
    #df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Below is an excerpt of my .CSV file:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2018-09-10 06:37:00,0.0001004,0.0001005,0.0001004,0.0001004,74.04
2018-09-10 06:38:00,0.0001004,0.0001004,0.0001004,0.0001004,0
2018-09-10 06:39:00,0.0001005,0.0001007,0.0001004,0.0001005,5946.72
2018-09-10 06:40:00,0.0001005,0.0001008,0.0001004,0.0001007,3188.36
2018-09-10 06:41:00,0.0001005,0.0001007,0.0001005,0.0001007,3278.77
```

Could anyone show me the correct code to load a .CSV like this to a Pandas dataframe? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please provide a test case that exhibits the failure you observe?
Also, what pandas version are you using?

If I take your example, there doesn't seem to be a problem at all:

```
In[1]:
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

Out[1]:

In[2]:
txt = """Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2018-09-10 06:37:00,0.0001004,0.0001005,0.0001004,0.0001004,74.04
2018-09-10 06:38:00,0.0001004,0.0001004,0.0001004,0.0001004,0
2018-09-10 06:39:00,0.0001005,0.0001007,0.0001004,0.0001005,5946.72
2018-09-10 06:40:00,0.0001005,0.0001008,0.0001004,0.0001007,3188.36
2018-09-10 06:41:00,0.0001005,0.0001007,0.0001005,0.0001007,3278.77
"""

Out[2]:

In[3]:
f = StringIO(txt)

Out[3]:

In[4]:
pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates=['Date'])

Out[4]:
                 Date    Open      High     Low     Close   Volume
0 2018-09-10 06:37:00  0.0001  0.000100  0.0001  0.000100    74.04
1 2018-09-10 06:38:00  0.0001  0.000100  0.0001  0.000100     0.00
2 2018-09-10 06:39:00  0.0001  0.000101  0.0001  0.000100  5946.72
3 2018-09-10 06:40:00  0.0001  0.000101  0.0001  0.000101  3188.36
4 2018-09-10 06:41:00  0.0001  0.000101  0.0001  0.000101  3278.77
```

Note: the above is with `pandas.__version__ == '0.24.0'`.

Comment: My Pandas is version 0.24.1

Comment: Thanks for verifying this. The problem is indeed elsewhere.

Comment: FWIW, sometimes there is noise buried in csv files. I found that often the best way to handle it is to try to use `pd.read_csv()` with as few parameters as possible, just to at least get the data in a DataFrame, and then filter, modify etc. until you get the dtypes you want.  In some extreme cases, it can be helpful to use an "adapter"; for example, I had a bunch of files that contain "Infinity" instead of "inf". The solution was to implement a `class ReplaceIOFile(io.TextIOBase)` that can be used to do on-the-fly replace.